# Get package references from a package body file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am extracting some information about package body files, and now I need to get the package references (packages invoked) in the same file. How to do this in Notepad++ with regex?

I understand that its possible with regex by marking a search with

```
pac_\w*
```

And unmark lines, but I need only the package names, not the lines.

For example if I have this code portion:

```
pac_test1.function1(...);
if pac_finally.f_result then
pac_execute.p_result;
v_load := pac_gui.f_show_result(pnum1, pnum2);
.
.
```

I expect to get this:

```
pac_test1
pac_finally
pac_execute
pac_gui
```

Or desired:

```
pac_test1, pac_finally, pac_execute, pac_gui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ may not be the right tool for this job, because the typical approach you would use would be to search for something like `pac_[^.]+`.  But the problem is that NPP operates starting with the entire line, and ending up some replacement of that line.  Lines which have no matches would need to be removed, and that is tricky.

So I recommend using an app language like PHP.  Here is a PHP script which can find all matches:

```
$script = "pac_test1.function1(...);
    if pac_finally.f_result then
    pac_execute.p_result;
    v_load := pac_gui.f_show_result(pnum1, pnum2);";
preg_match_all("/pac_[^.]+/", $script, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
echo implode(",", $matches[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => pac_test1
    [1] => pac_finally
    [2] => pac_execute
    [3] => pac_gui
)

pac_test1,pac_finally,pac_execute,pac_gui
```

Comment: [Here is a link](https://rextester.com/BAPL18883) to a demo, into which you may paste your source text to find all matches.

Comment: Maybe, but how I get the array like a csv (pac_test1, pac_finally, pac_execute, pac_gui)?   I'm not good in php

Comment: @reymagnus Use the `implode()` function, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Array to string conversion in source_file.php on line 2411  Array. I use echo implode(",",$arr);

Comment: Then you're not executing my script, which does not generate any such errors. I can't debug PHP code which I can't see.  If you can paste a demo link here, I'm happy to look at your code.  We could also try using another language, such as Java or C#, but it's the same thing really.

Comment: No issues, glad I could help you.  Goodnight.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G).*?(pac_\w+)(?:(?!pac_).)*(\R|\z)?`
- Replace with: `$1,`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\G)        # beginning of line OR restart from last match position
.*?             # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
(pac_\w+)       # group 1, pac_ followed by 1 or more word characters, the package
(?:(?!pac_).)*  # Tempered greedy token, make sure we haven't pac_
(\R|\z)?        # optional group 2, any kind of linebreak or end of file
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1,         # content of group 1, package, a comma and a space
```

**Given:**

```
pac_test1.function1(...); pac_test2
if pac_finally.f_result then
pac_execute.p_result;
v_load := pac_gui.f_show_result(pnum1, pnum2);
```

**Result for given example:**

```
pac_test1, pac_test2, pac_finally, pac_execute, pac_gui,
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: True, fixed.